# Jaxb - How to write xml elements with different names from the same class

Tags: jaxb

I have a list of items that should be marshalled as elements with different names in an xml document. Every item has a `String` field, `type`, and based on the value of that field, I know what element names should I write in the xml. So in my root element, I have a `List<Item> items`, and I can use the `@XmlElements` annotation, but how can I tell Jaxb which name should it use when marshalling?

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Form {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="textbox", type=Item.class),
        @XmlElement(name="checkbox", type=Item.class),
        @XmlElement(name="dropdown", type=Item.class)
    })
    private List<Item> items;

}
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
<form>
  <textbox ...> ... </textbox>
  <checkbox ...> ... </checkbox>
  <textbox ...> ... </textbox>
  <textbox ...> ... </textbox>
  <dropdown ...> ... </dropdown>
  ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on identical types (as opposed to different subtypes, each of which adds nothing to the base type) you are in for a little bit of a hassle.

```
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "bluebox", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "textbox", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "dropdown", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    })
    protected List> textboxOrCheckboxOrDropdown;

   public List> getTextboxOrCheckboxOrDropdown() {
        if (textboxOrCheckboxOrDropdown == null) {
            textboxOrCheckboxOrDropdown = new ArrayList>();
        }
        return this.textboxOrCheckboxOrDropdown;
    }
```

And your ObjectFactory might include methods such as

```
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "textbox", scope = Form.class)
    public JAXBElement createFormTextbox(BoxType value) {
        return new JAXBElement(_FormTextbox_QNAME, BoxType.class, Form.class, value);
    }
```

and likewise for checkbox and dropdown.

Things would be a little bit easier if you'd declare

```
class TextBox extends Item { /* empty */ }
```

and use this as the type for textbox elements and likewise for checkbox and dropdown.